# What does $L^2(S^1,\mu_H)$ mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, notation, topology, calculus

It's a Hilbert space, $\mu_H$ stands for the Haar measure on $U(1)$, but what does $S^1$ mean? I found it in one of my quantum mechanics books which approaches from a very 'mathematical' way.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the book?

Comment: $S^1$ is a circle, a "1-sphere". So this is the space of square-integrable functions over a periodic variable.

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense. @rob: I can't give a reference to the book, it's not written in english and it is not available online. But my question has been answered, thanks!

Comment: @user32109 Dead-tree references are also okay.

Comment: @MitchellPorter Please convert that comment to an answer.

Comment: $U(1)\cong S^1$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (Lie-)group $U(1)$ is the topological space $S^1$ (what we call a circle together with its standard open subsets) together with a rule how to multiply its points. In its representation as numbers in ${\mathbb C}$ with absolute value $1$, we have ${\mathrm e}^{{\mathrm i}\alpha}\bullet{\mathrm e}^{{\mathrm i}\beta}:={\mathrm e}^{{\mathrm i}\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}$.